# Enable jetty debug logging in a Spring project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, spring-ws, jetty-9

In Jetty 9 server's source code there is a lot of useful debug outputs. I am usung Spring 4.3.3 (that includes Jetty as a dependence) and is willing to **enable debug output of Jetty** (websocket part is most important) How could I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In spring boot in order to enable `DEBUG` logging you need to add the following to `application.properties`:

`logging.level.PACKAGE=DEBUG` where `PACKAGE` is the full java package of the classes you want to enable `DEBUG` logging on.

So for jetty it should be something like:

`logging.level.org.eclipse.jetty=DEBUG`

Or for websocket only:

`logging.level.org.eclipse.jetty.websocket=DEBUG`

Comment: This kinda sorta looks like `java.util.logging`, but the use of `DEBUG` (and not fine/er) makes that a bad assumption.  What is the logging implementation in use by Spring?

Comment: You can look at their docs to see all of this information: [Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html). From the docs, you can use `ERROR`, `WARN`, `INFO`, `DEBUG` or `TRACE` by default. Also, the question was how to enable `DEBUG` level logs so I gave it as an example.